# How do I get the name of the specific item being clicked in repeater?

Tags: asp.net, repeater

This is my repeater in aspx:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterR" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
         <table>
                    <a href="ViewRecipe.aspx">
                      <div class="property-image">
                        <div class="property-image-title">
                        </div>
                      </div></a>
                    <div class="property-description">
                      <h5><%# Eval("recipeName")%></h5>
                      <p><%#Eval("avgRating") %> stars</p>
                      <asp:Image class="img" runat="server" src=<%#Eval("recipePic") %> />
                    </div>
                    <a href="ViewRecipe.aspx">
                      <div class="property-social-icons">
                      </div>
                    </a>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

I want to get the name of the recipe being clicked so I can show it in ViewRecipe.aspx but I don't know How to recognize the item the user clicked on.

I can't use OnClick since I don't have a button, but a herf.
I wants to do it that way but I can't seem to find a solution

Comment: Read up on QueryString parameters. It is the simplest solution I think. `<a href="ViewRecipe.aspx?recipe=PARAM">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you don't have a button, so why not add one?

Just add a "image" button in place of the image.

So, this markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepeaterR" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div style="border: solid; padding: 10px; width: 15%; 
                margin-bottom: 8px; text-align: center">

            <a href="ViewRecipe.aspx">
                <div class="property-image">
                    <div class="property-image-title">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
            <div class="property-description">
                <h5 id="h5Fighter" runat="server"><%# Eval("Fighter")%></h5>
                <p id="pThrust" runat="server">Engine Thrust = <%#Eval("Thrust") %> stars</p>

                <asp:ImageButton ID="cmdView" runat="server"
                    ImageUrl='<%#Eval("ImagePath") %>'
                    Width="160px"
                    OnClick="cmdView_Click"
                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />

            </div>
            <a href="ViewRecipe.aspx">
                <div class="property-social-icons">
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

code to load:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        Loaddata
    End If
End Sub

Sub LoadData()

    RepeaterR.DataSource = Myrst("SELECT * FROM Fighters")
    RepeaterR.DataBind()

End Sub
```

And we get this:

[image]

And our image button code is:

```
Protected Sub cmdView_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs)

    Dim iBtn As ImageButton = sender
    Dim rRow As RepeaterItem = iBtn.NamingContainer

    Debug.Print($"Repeater row click = {rRow.ItemIndex}")
    Debug.Print($"Database PK id = {iBtn.CommandArgument}")

    Dim hFighter As HtmlGenericControl = rRow.FindControl("h5Fighter")
    Debug.Print($"Figher name = {hFighter.InnerText}")

    Dim pThrust As HtmlGenericControl = rRow.FindControl("pThrust")
    Debug.Print($"Engine thrust = {pThrust.InnerText}")

    Session("ReceipeID") = iBtn.CommandArgument

    'Response.Redirect("~/RecipeDetails.aspx")

End Sub
```

output of a click:

```
Repeater row click = 3
Database PK id = 4
Fighter name = Lockheed Martin F-35 Lightning II
```

So, while you don't have a button, then in place of a image, use a image button.

The above code shows how to get/grab/enjoy the current row click.

And it also shows how to grab/get controls from that current row click.

After that, you can shove value into session, or pass via URL parameter's, or whatever (and thus you can use/enjoy/have code to navigate to the next page in question, and passing along the required information in a number of ways.